# “On my own way vs. “in my own way”?

Tags: phrase-meaning, prepositional-phrases

Which one is correct **in or on** own way?

> - I usually help my closest friends on/in my own way.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*In my own way* is the idiomatically correct expression. I can't think of a situation where I would use *on my own way.*

Now, *in my way* and *on my way* are both valid expressions. You could say *in my way* instead of *in my own way* if you wanted to; the *own* just provides a bit of emphasis.

If I am *on my way*, I am proceeding to an expected destination. One more thing:

> You are in my way.
>   I am in my own way.

In this case, *in my way* means interfering or preventing me from doing something, most typically moving from one place to another. If, for example, you are standing in a doorway and I'm trying to go through it, you're in my way.

Now, if *I am in my own way*, it means that I'm creating difficulties for myself in accomplishing a task. For example, if I'm trying to lose weight and won't stop eating, I am in my own way. (In this case it would be more common to say *I'm getting in my own way.*)

Comment: If you'd like a situation for *on my own way*: "I got Louise on her way 10 minutes ago, so she should make it on time. I'll be on my own way soon, but might arrive a few minutes late". It's a rather contrived example, but it does "work" for me, as *own* is used to emphasise that I am now talking about myself rather than Louise.

Comment: @AndyT I still would never say it like that.  I would simply emphasize the 'my'.  "I'll be on _my_ way soon."

Comment: @AndyT's example works for me; and I'd my English is fairly bog standard British English.

Comment: Where are you from @Kevin?

Comment: @Wilson I'm from the U.S. but I've traveled a good bit. Google's [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+my+own+way%2Con+my+own+way&year_start=1800&year_end=2017&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20my%20own%20way%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20my%20own%20way%3B%2Cc0) confirms my experience, even for BE

Comment: "I usually help my closest friends in my own way" is much less ambiguous to me than "I usually help my closest friends in my way".  As you pointed out, "in my way" typically implies some form of interference and I don't think I'd pick up the intended meaning of "in my [own] way" without "own" being present.

Comment: @AndyT Good catch!

Comment: @Kevin - Er, no. Your ngram link doesn't confirm your experience. Your experience is that you would never use "on my own way"; the ngram shows that "in my own way" is far more common than "on my own way", but the latter does still get used occasionally.

Comment: @AndyT My experience is that I've never heard it used that way.  Ngram shows that those words almost never appear in print in that order.  Some of those hits are likely not this expression but something along the lines of "I know you'd probably just fight him, but I'll take him on my own way." where "on" is part of a previous part of the sentence that just happens to come before "my own way".

Comment: @AndyT A more focused Ngram search for _be_ on my way vs _be_ on my own way further supports this.  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=be+on+my+way%2C+be+on+my+own+way&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbe%20on%20my%20way%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Kevin - Your original ngram contains a [link](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22on+my+own+way%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr,ssl&dcr=0&ei=DncEWo7zLMelwQKs1LTwCQ) to the hits for "on my own way". You are correct that some of the hits have "on" as part of a separate clause. But there are also e.g. *"Bonny was an alcoholic now and I was well on my own way to breaking her record"* and "*once again headed off on my own way, but this time in the direction of Andorra*". So what do we have: the usage is *possible*, however it is *unusual*. Which supports my point.

Comment: @AndyT my point was not to contradict yours.  You can say whatever you want.  I was addressing Wilson who claimed it was common usage.

Comment: @Kevin - [AndyT slaps his head]. So you were. My apologies. I'm not sure whether Wilson meant that "using *own* for emphasis is common" or "the whole phrase is common". I agree with you that the whole phrase is certainly not common.

Comment: Can we leave out 'in' and just say "I usually help my closes friend my own way?"

Comment: @Ashraf I think you mean "closest" rather than "closes"? If so, then yes, this is quite common, especially in simpler sentences such as "I'd like to do it my own way" or even "I'd like to do it my way."

Answer (score 10):

"In my way" refers to the definition of *way* as "preference", or "style", so it would be more appropriate here:

> Frank Sinatra sang that he always did things **in his own way**.

"On my way" refers to the definition of *way* as "route" or "path".

> **On my way** to school I saw my old friend Jim.

However, "in my way" can also refer to something *obstructing* your path:

> The train was delayed because a herd of cows was **in the way**.

Answer (score 5):

In your case, definitely "in my own way".

"in [my/your/her] own way" means "in a way that is special to that person". The only time that "on" and "way" are used together (that I can think of) is in "on [my/your/her/the] way" which means you are in the process of coming somewhere (e.g., "I am on my way to the store.").